# How to modify LibGdx actor properties on hit event

Tags: libgdx

I'm using Actor class in my game for several advantages of Actors class. But currently I'm facing an issue on using Stage.hit(...) method.

As we know, "hit" returns Actor object.

```
public class Enemy extends Actor
{
    int health = 100;

public Enemy (int type, float x, float y)
{
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
}

public void act(float deltaTime)
{               
    Actor hitActor = GameAsset.stage.hit(getX(), getY(), false);
    if(hitActor != null))
    {
               health -= 10;
               // next, should be reducing hitActor health in stage, but how?
    }
}
...
```

The question is, is there any way to do in the comments above?

Sorry for bad english :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this inside the `hitActor != null` test:

```
if (hitActor instanceof Enemy) {
   Enemy e = (Enemy)hitActor;
   e.health -= 10;
}
```

That checks if the returned `Actor` happens to be an instance of the `Enemy` subclass.  If so, you can cast the object and apply the change.  If not, the hit is ignored.

You can learn more about casting objects from their generic types to more specific types here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html (especially the last section about "Casting Objects".